# Multi VPS: Best practice for semi-automated upgrades?

Tags: cron, scripting, apt, automation, upgrade

## I've got many virtual private servers, each needing some `apt-get upgrade -y` lovin' from time to time.

(Ubuntu 18.04)

### Problems I face:

- I don't have time to upgrade each one manually.
- I don't want to put `apt-get upgrade -y` into a routine `cron` task because I want to know and control the servers' state.
- Upgrading over breakable `ssh`?? Preach at me about the safeguards in place, but I'd rather pass.
- There's a [bug in the cloud images](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1747464) that might have been making interactive dialogs on upgrades (see the ubuntu-dev email below) ...I want to be bug-proof, kind of, if that's possible.

*(Presume I've got `apt update` solved.)*

### Proposed solution in-progress: *Run a test upgrade, then tell all other machine crons to upgrade—but how?*

1. Have a cron-run script that runs an `if... -f` test for a file, say `.medoupgrade`; if `true`, it runs the `apt-get upgrade -y` then deletes the `.medoupgrade` file.
2. I run a manual upgrade on my test server. If I'm happy, then I `ssh user@vps 'touch .medupgrade'` to my machines; each machine's cron will see it and upgrade one time.
3. *What in the name of Linus-Sam Hill should go in the `cron` upgrader script??*

### Two questions, kind of:

#### 1. Is my above method in 1–2 so far okay? Silly? Smart? Someone already dunnit?

I mean, I don't exactly see loads of people talking about their cron updates looking for `.medoupgrade` jobs. I can't find any, actually. But, I also don't see people blogging everyday about some other standard way to upgrade multiple servers at once either. All I see is everyone doing `apt-get upgrade -y` on their servers like it's from a favorite tattoo shop—or coffee mug.

## *My $64,000 Question:*

#### 2. What "safely" goes into a script that runs `apt-get upgrade -y`?

Is it safe to just put `apt-get upgrade -y` into a script on a VPS?

*If I'm going to have a script run an upgrade while I'm not watching—not regularly, but still while I'm not watching—what's the safest way?*

---

### Digging already done:

They answered me: *Ubuntu-devel-discuss Digest, Vol 144, Issue 13 – **1. Re: No more dialog in `apt upgrade -y` events***

Here's the important part of what they said:

> In your case, using DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive, running apt-get
>   with -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o
>   Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" and redirecting stdin from /dev/null
>   is probably appropriate.

Are they right, is that what I should run instead of `apt-get upgrade -y`? If so, what does all that look like in a script that's safe to run without me watching?